# Scraping content from a file

Tags: php, xml, web-scraping

I have a file that contains many of these

```
<sync start="14400">
   <p class="ENCC">
     Removed
   </p>
</sync>
```

and I would like to turn them into this format

```
<p begin="00:00:33.3" end="00:00:35.8">Removed</p>
```

I would like to get the data inside start="" and the data inside  and loop through until I have all of them on the page.

I have been trying to do this for a few hours now but could do with a point in the right direction. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Edit: also please ignore the start/behin formatting I already have the code to do that

Comment: Have you looked into XSLT at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're after is a simple way to parse XML, look into [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (very accessible if you're used to jQuery). The code would look something like (untested):

```
$start_values = array ();
$content_values = array ();
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentXML ($xml);
foreach (pq ('sync') as $node)
{
  $start_values[] = pq ($node)->attr ('start');
  $content_values[] = pq ($node)->find ('p')->html ();
}
```

`$start_values` would then be an array with the respective values for the start-attribute and `$content_values` would be an array with the respective content of the actual tag.

**UPDATED**

I noticed that I didn't take the p-node under sync into consideration earlier. The `find ('p')` part should take care of that.